# FFMPEG SreenRecorder with Audio does not add DrawText

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG to record the whole screen using gdigrab as well as recording the microphone audio and virtual-audio-capturer. It has taken a good while, but I got it to work and save as an mkv file. I am using Vb.net to pass the string to FFMPEG. Here is the string.

"/k ffmpeg.exe -y -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{16F2BCE9-4F86-4C29-8B2C-B70508551DC7} -f dshow -i audio=@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935} -f gdigrab -framerate 50 -i desktop -codec:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 -vf drawtext=fontfile=C:\Windows\ARLRDBD.TTF:Text=" & MyProgName & "fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:shadowcolor=darkblue:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:boxcolor=blue@0.6:boxborderw=5:x=50:y=H-th-50:-filter_complex [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a] -map 2 -map [a] " & str & "\Recordings\ScreenRecorder" & FileTime & ".mkv"

The problem is that it will not draw the text on the screen and I get the following error.

```
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
    Input #0, dshow, from 'audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43- 
    00A0C911CE86}\wave_{16F2BCE9-4F86-4C29-8B2C-B70508551DC7}':
    Duration: N/A, start: 840168.175000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : stereo
    Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43- 
    00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935}':
    Duration: N/A, start: 840168.949000, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    [gdigrab @ 000001b92bad9880] Capturing whole desktop as 
    1366x768x32 at (0,0)
    [gdigrab @ 000001b92bad9880] Stream #0: not enough frames to 
    estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
    Input #2, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
    Duration: N/A, start: 1602928621.299032, bitrate: 1678562 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1366x768, 1678562 kb/s, 50 fps, 
    1000k tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
    [NULL @ 000001b92badb300] Unable to find a suitable output format 
    for '[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]'
    [0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]: Invalid argument
    Received stop event after 9 passes
```

If anyone can see where I am going wrong and point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use both `-vf` and `-filter_complex`. Just use `-filter_complex`:

```
"/k ffmpeg.exe -y -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{16F2BCE9-4F86-4C29-8B2C-B70508551DC7} -f dshow -i audio=@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935} -f gdigrab -framerate 50 -i desktop -codec:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 -filter_complex drawtext=fontfile=C:\Windows\ARLRDBD.TTF:text=" & MyProgName & "fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:shadowcolor=darkblue:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:boxcolor=blue@0.6:boxborderw=5:x=50:y=H-th-50[v];[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a] -map [v] -map [a] " & str & "\Recordings\ScreenRecorder" & FileTime & ".mkv"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response llogan, I now get this error Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=C:WindowsARLRDBD.TTF:Text=SnatchMediaPlayer:fontcolor=white:fontsize=24:box=1:shadowcolor=darkblue:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:boxcolor=blue@0.6:boxborderw=5:x=50:y=H-th-50:'

Comment: When I used your example, the first error was 'could not find audio' device. So I fixed that. Then it was Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 00000275c5ffa080] Option 'Text' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000275c5ffc3c0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=C:WindowsARLRDBD.TTF:Text=SnatchMediaPlayerfontcolo

Comment: After adding a few pipes just to help tidy the code/script up it is this error Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 00000275c5ffa080] Option 'Text' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000275c5ffc3c0] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=C:WindowsARLRDBD.TTF:Text=SnatchMediaPlayerfontcolo etc etc I feel like I am so close, I have hunted online but not seen any similar examples at all, using full screen and audio.

Comment: @JohnHenderson Option name is `text`, not `Text`.